# Getting span on top of specific image in an li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Im basicly trying to get my span to show on mouseover and that works as intended. What I want to do is get the spans to the correct images, because I plan on filling that list with more stuff.

This is how it looks like now: http://jsfiddle.net/uc8jc/539/

Heres my code:

```
<ul class="frontpagephotos">
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.myrtlebeachproduce.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Banana-300x300.jpg" alt="Jogginglarms armband" />
    <span>Jogginglarms armband</span>
  </li>
    <li>
    <img src="http://www.myrtlebeachproduce.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Banana-300x300.jpg" alt="Jogginglarms armband" />
    <span>Jogginglarms armband</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("span").hide();



$(".frontpagephotos").on("mouseenter", "li", togglePhotos);
    $(".frontpagephotos").on("mouseleave", "li", togglePhotos);

    function togglePhotos() {
        $(this).find("span").slideToggle("fast");
    }
});
```

and the css:

```
ul.frontpagephotos li{
    display: inline;    
}
ul.frontpagephotos li img{
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
ul.frontpagephotos span{
    position: absolute;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 18em;
    margin-top: -2.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Appreciate any answers, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your `span` has the `position: absolute` property, so it's positoned relative inside the next parent with `position: relative`. It *should* be positioned relative inside the `li`, but actually the next parent with `position: relative` is the body (or window?).

The simple solution: Change your CSS code to this:

```
ul.frontpagephotos li {
    display: inline-block;  
    position: relative;
}
```

When the `li` has `position: relative`, the `span` is positioned relative inside the `li`. You also need `block` or `inline-block` in order to be able to set `position: relative`.

That's it! Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uc8jc/545/

Comment: Oh, thanks for explaining, I understand it now. Thanks a lot, cheers bud!

Comment: Great! If this answer helped you, could you please accept and/or upvote my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could use hover instead, and just pass $(this) into the functions for on and off states:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('span').hide();
  $("img").hover(function(){
    togglePhotos($(this));
  },
  function(){
    togglePhotos($(this));
  });

  function togglePhotos(obj) {
    obj.next().slideToggle();
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uc8jc/544/